# SwiftUI ObjectBinding won't receive didchange update from bindable object using combine

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm testing the Combine framework and using BindableObject as a notification hub for passing data among several views in a SwiftUI ContentView.

One of the views is a table. I click on a row and the value is detected in the print checkpoint, so the bindableobject receives the update.

Problem is, the new string is not broadcasted to the receiving end on the ContentView.

I'm new to this.

View controller with a table view .swift (broadcaster):

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final public class NewestString: BindableObject {

    public var didChange = PassthroughSubject<NewestString, Never>()

    var newstring: String {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
            print("Newstring: \(newstring)") //<-- Change detected
        }
    }

    init(newstring: String) {
        self.newstring = newstring
    }

    public func update() {
        didChange.send(self)
        print("--Newstring: \(newstring)")

    }

}



final class AViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var someTableView: UITableView!
    var returnData = NewestString(newstring:"--")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}

/// [.....] More extensions here

extension AViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let completion = someResults[indexPath.row]

    //// [......] More code here

        self.returnData.newstring = "Test string" //<--- change caused 
        }
    }
}
```

Main content View (broadcast destination):

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct PrimaryButton: View {
    var title: String = "DefaultTitle"
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { print("tapped") }) {
            Text(title)
        }
   }

}


struct MyMiniView: View {
    @State var aTitle: String = "InitialView"
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            PrimaryButton(title: aTitle)
            }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selection = 0
    @ObjectBinding var desiredString: NewestString = NewestString(newstring: "Elegir destino") // <-- Expected receiver

    var body: some View {

        TabbedView(selection: $selection){

            ZStack() {

                MyMiniView(aTitle: self.desiredString.newstring ?? "--")
               // expected end use of the change, that never happens
[...]
}

struct AView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewControllerType = AViewController


    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AView>) -> AViewController {


        return UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: String(describing: AViewController.self)) as! AViewController

    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AView>) {
        //
    }
```

It compiles, runs and prints the change, but no update happens to the MyMiniView's PrimaryButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find where you are using your instance of `AViewController`, but the issue comes from the fact that you are using multiple instance of your bindable object `NewestString`.

The `ContentView` as an instance of `NewestString`, which every update will trigger a view reload.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selection = 0

    // First instance is here
    @ObjectBinding var desiredString: NewestString = NewestString(newstring: "Elegir destino") // <-- Expected receiver
}
```

The second instance of `NewestString` is in `AViewController`, which you actually modify. But, as it's not the same instance of `NewestString` (the one that is actually declared in the content view), modifying it doesn't trigger the view reload.

```swift
final class AViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var someTableView: UITableView!
    // The second instance is here
    var returnData = NewestString(newstring:"--")
}
```

To solve this, you need to find a way to "forward" the instance of `NewestString` created inside your your `ContentView` to the view controller.

#### Edit: Found a way to pass the instance of the `ObjectBinding` to the view controller:

When you add your view into the hierarchy using SwiftUI, you need to pass a `Binding` of the value that you want to access from the view controller:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObjectBinding var desiredString = NewestString(newstring: "Hello")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AView(binding: desiredString[\.newstring])
            Text(desiredString.newstring)
        }
    }
}
```

> The `subscript` with a key path will produce a `Binding` of the given property:
>
> ```swift
> protocol BindableObject {
>     subscript<T>(keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Self, T>) -> > Binding<T> { get }
> }
> ```

In the view controller wrapper (`UIViewControllerRepresentable`), you need to forward the given `Binding` to the actual view controller instance.

```swift
struct AView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = AViewController

    var binding: Binding<String>

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AView>) -> AViewController {
        let controller = AViewController()
        controller.stringBinding = binding // forward the binding object
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AView>) {

    }
}
```

And then, in you view controller, you can use the binding to update your value (using the `.value` property):

```swift
final class AViewController: UIViewController {
    var stringBinding: Binding<String>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        stringBinding.value = "Hello world !!"
    }
}
```

When the view controller's `viewDidLoad` is called, the `desiredString` (in `ContentView`) will be updated to "Hello world !!", just like the displayed text (`Text(desiredString.newstring)`).

Comment: Thanks @rraphael. I can see the problem as exposed by you. I have added the UIViewControllerRepresentable code that brings AView to life. The UIView is wrapped and I can't figure out how to pass the initialized ObjectBinding

Comment: @jpelayo Found a way to pass the `ObjectBinding` to the wrapped `UIViewController`. See the "edit" part of the answer.